# Battery issue in Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Tags: 18.04

I have Install **Ubuntu 18.04**.Battery is draining very quickly approx 1:30 hr only. while in window same laptop have upto 4:50 hr battery.
I have Lenovo Ideapad 310 (i5 6th gen).

Answer (score 4):

First, read this Ubuntu Help article about [Power & battery](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/power.html)

If not enough you may want to install [TLP](https://linrunner.de/en/tlp/docs/tlp-linux-advanced-power-management.html)

*TLP brings you the benefits of advanced power management for Linux
without the need to understand every technical detail. TLP comes with
a default configuration already optimized for battery life, so you may
just install and forget it. Nevertheless, TLP is highly customizable to
fulfill your specific requirements.*

To install TLP :

```
sudo apt install tlp tlp-rdw
sudo tlp start
```

Then customize suspend setting: **System Settings** -> **Power** -> **Suspend & Power Button**.