# Installed Ubuntu 18.04 on my laptop, now my battery will die within minutes

Tags: 18.04, battery

I did a bit of research and it seems like `powertop` can inform me about battery usage. This is what it gives me. [image]

GPU is off and CPU is only at 17%.

I wouldn't know where to start so I can give additional details as requested.

If i run `acpi -bi`, I get:

```
Battery 0: Discharging, 100%, 01:38:45 remaining
Battery 0: design capacity 1664 mAh, last full capacity 1664 mAh = 100%
```

Comment: may be this could help : https://askubuntu.com/a/1042315/77093

Comment: I will look into it, thank you.

Comment: Edit your question and show me `acpi -bi`.

Comment: ok i've done it